# New to docker, Not seeing local changes made on site

Tags: docker

I've been working on a site using laravel 5.8 which runs on a docker container and usually I've been able to save my local changes and the site on my local host reflects them but not my changes aren't seen on the site.

I'm running `docker-compose up -d` and it starts with the laravel driver, creating php and creating nginx but My local changes just won't show.

Should I be running a different command?

```
docker-compose file:

version: '3'

networks:
laravel:

services:
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
        - ./resources/docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
        - php
    networks:
        - laravel
php:
    image: quay.io/testRepo/docker-php-iaccess-odbc:7.3-devel
    container_name: php
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
    environment:
        - PHP_OPACHE_ENABLE=0
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    networks:
        - laravel
```

Comment: instead of "./" could you try to put the absolute path to source code on local machine?

Comment: would I need to start at the C:/ level? So in nginx and php I would say ```C:/repo/testSite/:/var/www``` ?

Comment: Yes of course :) never did that on windows by the way... don't know if it can be related to this

Comment: I guess that could be a potential issue. I do feel like it has to do with the volume mapping though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose volume mounting requires either a  full path or using the Version 3 `bind` configuration.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes

In Linux/Unix OSes the `pwd` CLI command can be used as a short cut.

Comment: Thank you, this does make some sense. However, I did get a normal blade change to show, it seems like it's only my vue component files ```.vue``` that aren't actually showing live

Comment: Ah, that is good to hear. Check the applications .dockerignore file, make sure there is not a rule ignoring `.*` files. Often times dot files are ignored as they are configuration for tooling.